# Publishing Ethics: not listing Professor's name

Tags: publications, advisor, ethics, paper-submission

I did summer research work with a Professor who is not my adviser. He gave me a big topic (big enough that doesn’t help you to navigate to a specific area) and but didn’t contribute much.

Now after the summer, I continue to work on this without his guidance, and got some good results. I am thinking of publishing the paper. I don’t know if I should ask whether he wants his name on the paper.

Also, I was wondering what happen if he decided to block my paper from publishing? (I knew he always wanted the paper to be submitted to Venue A, but I want to submit to Venue B). Does he have the right to do so?

---

This Professor is from the same school of mine.

Comment: Why not simply ask for his feedback on the paper? Then, if he wants his name on it he will find a way to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask for his feedback **and** if he would like his name on it at the same time?

He has two responses:

Yes, I’ll give you feedback and would welcome my name on the paper.

Or: happy to provide feedback, but due to X, can’t put my name on the paper, thanks for asking though.

I have assumed that he won’t refuse to provide feedback. The first option may lead to a better paper.